# How to open a form on fav-icon click?

Tags: asp.net, javascript

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon_012423/favicon.ico"/>
<link rel="icon" type="image/gif" href="favicon_012423/animated_favicon1.gif" />
```

I want to pop up or open a new form on the click of a fav-icon. Can anybody help me out with this? Thanks

Comment: I would suggest you to open new form on page logo(Generally on Top-left) click instead on favicon.

Comment: Neeraj,i am afraid you can't do tht :)

Answer (score 1):

you can't open a link off of a favicon... favicons are outside your markup and thus you cannot add an anchor tag to it.

Answer (score 1):

It is impossible because FavIcon is not a part of your code.

Your icon just download to users computer and then his/her browser try to use it in its own way.